# iOS - Add a cell to empty UITableView Section w/ Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I'm using Core Data and an NSFetchedResults controller to populate a UITableViewCell (plain style) in my app. The TableView has 3 sections, each with a viewForHeaderInSection and a viewForFooterInSection. The user will be entering items that will be put in each section.

When one of the sections has no items in it, it completely disappears. I'm wondering if it would be possible to make it so if a section is empty, it would display a new cell that would say "no entries" or something like that (maybe with a UIImageView or another view?), which would then go away if a new item was put into that section.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here's the code for my data source.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
   return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}
```

Also, the section itself gets removed from the TableView when it has no rows, so how could I make it so the "no entries" cell gets added to the correct section?

Answer (score 1):

If the section don't appear in the table view, it isn't returning from the fetch results, despite the fact you said you have 3 sections. 
You can return it manually by:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
```

Then

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
   if  ([[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects] == 0){     
       return 1;
   } else {
       return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
   }
}
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` test for empty..

```
if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects] == 0){
cell.textLabel = @"No Entries";
```

}

Just a idea.

EDIT: Be careful, if you try to catch a index that isn't returned by the fetch, your app can crash.

Comment: when I set numberOfSectionsInTableView to 3, I get a crash on launch. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, your fetch results isn't returning 3 sections. Then you try to access a null data.. and bam, crash. Take a look at your Core Data, and try to handle your data accordingly... You want to have 3 sections.. but you don't have this data. I believe your crash is here: [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `numberOfRowsInSection` function to check if there are no real rows for that section, and return 1 if that is the case (instead of 0).

Then, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check if you have data for that section, and just create your "no entries" cell when you see that you don't.